# how to call splitview controller delegate method manually?

Tags: iphone, ios4, uisplitviewcontroller

I am using SplitviewController in Tabbar based application, First i tap on setting(with Splitviewcontroller) then delegate method of splitview controller is called , but when i tap on another tab after then change the orientation & then reopen settings(with splitviewcontroller) then delegate method of splitviewcontroller is not called .......

I know that that time only viewWillAppear method is called , but i want called delegate method of splitViewcontroller at that time...Please tell me how to call delegate method splitviewController at that time.

Thanks in advance.....Please help me....

in masterview controller

```
- (void)splitViewController:(UISplitViewController*)svc willHideViewController:(UIViewController *)aViewController withBarButtonItem:(UIBarButtonItem*)barButtonItem forPopoverController:(UIPopoverController*)pc {

    // Keep references to the popover controller and the popover button, and tell the detail view controller to show the button.
    barButtonItem.title = @"Settings";
    self.popoverController = pc;
    self.rootPopoverButtonItem = barButtonItem;
UINavigationController *nav = [self.splitViewController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:1];
UIViewController <SubstitutableDetailViewController> *detailViewController = [nav.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0];
    [detailViewController showRootPopoverButtonItem:rootPopoverButtonItem]; 
}

- (void)splitViewController:(UISplitViewController*)svc willShowViewController:(UIViewController *)aViewController invalidatingBarButtonItem:(UIBarButtonItem *)barButtonItem {

UINavigationController *nav = [self.splitViewController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:1];
    UIViewController <SubstitutableDetailViewController> *detailViewController = [nav.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0];
    [detailViewController invalidateRootPopoverButtonItem:rootPopoverButtonItem];
    self.popoverController = nil;
    self.rootPopoverButtonItem = nil;
}
```

in detail view

```
- (void)showRootPopoverButtonItem:(UIBarButtonItem *)barButtonItem {
// Add the popover button to the left navigation item.
[self.navigationController.navigationBar.topItem setLeftBarButtonItem:barButtonItem animated:NO];
}

- (void)invalidateRootPopoverButtonItem:(UIBarButtonItem *)barButtonItem {
// Remove the popover button.
[self.navigationController.navigationBar.topItem setLeftBarButtonItem:nil animated:NO];
}
```

Comment: Provide code, so we can see where are your problems

Comment: Code is much more .....which code i can post here?

Comment: Code that should launch your method but it does not.

Comment: Is there any one got solution for this? Same requirement here. Thanks,